# NLog internal log success messages

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to use NLog in my app after creating the log configuration programmatically, but I cannot output any logs, and so in order to debug my app I defined:

```
LogManager.ThrowException = true;
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace
InternalLogger.LogFile = "SomeLog.txt"
```

After reviewing the internal log output I can't see any indication of it trying to, much less succeeding nor failing to log something (flushing aside). Is it normal?

The internal log:

```
2016-08-03 16:34:01.4679 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5639 Debug Start auto loading, location: C:\Users\ME\Source\Repos\MyRepos\Soulotion\Project\bin\Debug
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5639 Info Auto loading assembly file:  C:\Users\ME\Source\Repos\MyRepos\Soulotion\Project\bin\Debug\Project.dll
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5729 Info Project, Version=1.0.6059.26892, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. File version: 1.0.*. Product version: 1.0.*.
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5729 Debug ScanAssembly('Project, Version=1.0.6059.26892, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5729 Info Auto loading assembly file:   C:\Users\ME\Source\Repos\MyRepos\Soulotion\Project\bin\Debug\Project.dll succeeded!
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5729 Debug Auto loading done
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5929 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.5929 Trace Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6059 Debug Setting 'UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper.uppercase' to 'true'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6059 Trace Wrapping LevelLayoutRenderer with UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6329 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6329 Trace Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6489 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6489 Trace Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6619 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6619 Trace   Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6769 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6769 Trace Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6769 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6769 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6929 Debug Registering target eventlog: NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6929 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.6929 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7089 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7089 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7089 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7089 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7089 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7259 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7259 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7419 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7419 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7419 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7419 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7419 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7419 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7589 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7589 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7589 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7589 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7709 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7709 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7709 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7709 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7919 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7919 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7919 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.7919 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8039 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8039 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8039 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8039 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8039 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8179 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8179 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8179 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8179 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8179 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8179 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8389 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8389 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8389 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8389 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8579 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8579 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8639 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8639 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8639 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8639 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8639 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8639 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8829 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8829 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8829 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8829 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8989 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8989 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8989 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.8989 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9149 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9149 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9149 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9149 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9309 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9309 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''CompName''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9309 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9309 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9499 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9499 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9569 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9569 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9569 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9569 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9739 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9739 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9739 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9739 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9899 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9899 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9899 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''CompName''
2016-08-03 16:34:01.9899 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0139 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0139 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0219 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0219 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0389 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0389 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0389 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0389 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0519 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0519 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0519 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0519 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0519 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0519 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0719 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0719 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0719 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0719 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0849 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0849 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0849 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0849 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0980 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0980 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0980 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0980 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0980 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.0980 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1170 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''CompName''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1170 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1170 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1170 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1300 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1300 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1300 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1300 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1300 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1300 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1500 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1500 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1500 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1500 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1630 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1630 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1630 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1630 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1760 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1760 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1920 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1920 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1920 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1920 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1920 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.1920 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2120 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2120 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2120 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2120 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2250 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2250 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2250 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2250 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2380 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2380 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2380 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2380 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2380 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2380 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2570 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2570 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2570 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2570 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2700 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2700 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2700 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2700 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2700 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2850 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2850 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2850 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2850 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.2850 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3040 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3040 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3040 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3040 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace>:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3170 Trace Scanning TargetWithFilterChain 'NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3170 Trace  Scanning EventLogTarget 'EventLog Target[eventlog]'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3170 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''MaglanNG''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3170 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3170 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3170 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3370 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3370 Trace    Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3370 Trace     Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3370 Trace      Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3500 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3500 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3500 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3500 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3630 Debug Targets for NlogPlugin by level:
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3630 Debug Trace => eventlog
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3630 Debug Debug => eventlog
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3630 Debug Info => eventlog
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3630 Debug Warn => eventlog
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3630 Debug Error => eventlog
2016-08-03 16:34:02.3820 Debug Fatal => eventlog
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3321 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3321 Trace Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3321 Debug Setting 'UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper.uppercase' to 'true'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3321 Trace Wrapping LevelLayoutRenderer with UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3321 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3481 Trace Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3481 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3481 Trace Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3481 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3611 Trace   Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3611 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3611 Trace Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3611 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3751 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3751 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3751 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2016-08-03 16:34:04.3751 Debug Registering target file: NLog.Targets.FileTarget
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9491 Trace LogFactory.Flush(00:00:15)
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9491 Trace Flushing all targets...
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9491 Trace ForEachItemInParallel() 2 items
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9931 Trace Continuation invoked: 
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9931 Trace Continuation invoked: 
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9931 Trace Parallel task completed. 1 items remaining
2016-08-03 16:34:21.9931 Trace Parallel task completed. 0 items remaining
2016-08-03 16:34:25.0153 Trace LogFactory.Flush(00:00:15)
2016-08-03 16:34:25.0153 Trace Flushing all targets...
2016-08-03 16:34:25.0153 Trace ForEachItemInParallel() 2 items
2016-08-03 16:34:25.0303 Trace Continuation invoked: 
2016-08-03 16:34:25.0303 Trace Parallel task completed. 1 items remaining
2016-08-03 16:34:25.0303 Trace Parallel task completed. 0 items remaining
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0654 Info Shutting down logging...
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0654 Info Closing old configuration.
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0654 Trace LogFactory.Flush(00:00:15)
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0654 Trace Flushing all targets...
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0654 Trace ForEachItemInParallel() 2 items
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0734 Trace Continuation invoked: 
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0734 Trace Parallel task completed. 1 items remaining
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0734 Debug Closing logging configuration...
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0734 Debug Finished closing logging configuration.
2016-08-03 16:34:28.0734 Info Logger has been shut down.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no error, but the last line:

> 2016-08-03 16:34:28.0734 Info Logger has been shut down.

indicated that the logger has been stopped because the app domain is unloaded or exited. See the [log message in the source code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/96b6bce5fbb89218a3a1e7007d78197b8b8983aa/src/NLog/LogManager.cs#L437) and the [calls in the source code part 1](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/96b6bce5fbb89218a3a1e7007d78197b8b8983aa/src/NLog/LogManager.cs#L386-L387)  and [part 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/96b6bce5fbb89218a3a1e7007d78197b8b8983aa/src/NLog/LogManager.cs#L144-L145)